# ViewController's View display late after Complete process of viewWillAppear so can not display progressbar

Tags: ios, view, progress-bar, loadview

I'm working on Contact App so in my home screen if user first time open the app than it take permission of contact access and if not first time than it only fetch whole contact and i have up to 500 contacts.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self getContactPermissionAndContacts]; //this method called for get permission or fetching contacts.
}
```

In my above code all the things works but I've lots of contacts so i want to put progressbar when calling getContactPermissionAndContacts method and i put progressbar code in first line in this method for showing progressbar.

But the main problem is that when i execute my app splash screen display and at that time this processes are execute after than the view was display so i can't see the progressbar.

And also this problem i face int another view when i refresh the all contacts.

So is there a way to display view first and after display (Load) view we start process for fetching contacts.

Delay is one of the option but is there another option to display the view first.

if is there another way than please share your answer will be appreciated.
Thank U!

Comment: what about using block?

Comment: Sorry delays and block i reject because there is also some background processes so i can't manage it

Comment: if there is no options than i decided to delay the method call it is the best way i thought.

Comment: block is not something which delays your processing .

Comment: ya i know but block is also work in background so can't manage the other code Because the process of block is execute after outer block is execute

Comment: So the code sequence will change and if it is change than i got very big trouble B'coz i almost complete the app just this progressbar thing is remain.